# Javascript how to return True if a variable called 'payroll_no' (20 long string) contains only numerics and false if it has any characters

Tags: javascript, numeric

```
if  (!Character.isDigit(payroll_no))

{

   document.getElementById('field_117219').value ='We do not have your payroll number please email it to us')

}

else

 {

    Name = document.getElementById('field_115676').value;

    document.getElementById('field_117219').value ="Appraisal Details for "+Name;

     iframe_115667.location.replace('/sorce/apps/enh/asp/Appraisals.aspxgridname=Appraisals&Payroll_no='+Payroll_no);


}
```

Comment: It's best to actually ask a question, not just post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `isNaN(payrol_no)`. It returns `false` if it is a number (hence the "is Not A Number"), and `true` otherwise.

Comment: That is even better - thank-you

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a regex to it:

```
if (/^\d+$/.test(payrol_no)) {
    // Just digits
} else {
    // contains non-digit characters
}
```